# Azure AI Search fails to read blob metadata configured in search index

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-openai

I've uploaded less than 20 HTML documents to a blob container in an Azure Storage Account. Each file has two tags: `source_url` and `document_type`.

I've imported and vectorized data (with proper wizard in Overview blade) resulting in the creation of an Azure AI Search data source, index and indexer.

I've updated the index definition adding two retrievable and searchable fields with exact same name of tags. It follows definition grabbed from Azure Portal:

```json
{
  "name": "source_url",
  "type": "Edm.String",
  "searchable": true,
  "filterable": false,
  "retrievable": true,
  "sortable": false,
  "facetable": false,
  "key": false,
  "indexAnalyzer": null,
  "searchAnalyzer": null,
  "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
  "normalizer": null,
  "dimensions": null,
  "vectorSearchProfile": null,
  "synonymMaps": []
},
{
  "name": "document_type",
  "type": "Edm.String",
  "searchable": true,
  "filterable": false,
  "retrievable": true,
  "sortable": true,
  "facetable": false,
  "key": false,
  "indexAnalyzer": null,
  "searchAnalyzer": null,
  "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
  "normalizer": null,
  "dimensions": null,
  "vectorSearchProfile": null,
  "synonymMaps": []
}
```

When I try a search with a known document title (after index regeneration) I can see that both fields are always null:

```json
{
  "@odata.context": "https://reg-srch-eu-dev.search.windows.net/indexes('vector-docs-json-2')/$metadata#docs(*)",
  "@search.answers": [],
  "value": [
    {
      "@search.score": 0.016393441706895828,
      "@search.rerankerScore": 2.7293198108673096,
      "@search.captions": [
        {
          "text": "hua da trading, inc. - 664359 - 12_20_2023 _ fda.json. that...",
          "highlights": "<em>hua da trading, inc. - 664359</em> - 12_20_2023 _ fda.json. that..."
        }
      ],
      "chunk_id": "436dc57017d5_aHR0cHM6Ly9yZWdzYWV1ZGV2LmJsb2IuY29yZS53aW5kb3dzLm5ldC9kb2NzLWpzb24vZmRhL0h1YSUyMERhJTIwVHJhZGluZywlMjBJbmMuJTIwLSUyMDY2NDM1OSUyMC0lMjAxMl8yMF8yMDIzJTIwXyUyMEZEQS5qc29u0_pages_8",
      "parent_id": "aHR0cHM6Ly9yZWdzYWV1ZGV2LmJsb2IuY29yZS53aW5kb3dzLm5ldC9kb2NzLWpzb24vZmRhL0h1YSUyMERhJTIwVHJhZGluZywlMjBJbmMuJTIwLSUyMDY2NDM1OSUyMC0lMjAxMl8yMF8yMDIzJTIwXyUyMEZEQS5qc29u0",
      "chunk": "that you recalled 300 boxes of your “WeFun,” lot numbers 18520168 and 09/30/2026, due to presence of undeclared sildenafil in August 2023...",
      "title": "Hua Da Trading, Inc. - 664359 - 12_20_2023 _ FDA.json",
      "source_url": null,
      "document_type": null
    },
    //...
}
```

I've configured this Azure AI Search index in Azure OpenAI playground setting the source URL to the index field. The chat is able to extract documents by date (and reply to other questions) but cannot supply the source URL:

> The requested information is not available in the retrieved data.
> Please try another query or topic.

I'm wondering what I'm missing. What can I do so that blob tags are correctly mapped in the search index?

Answer (score 0):

As in [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#indexing-blob-metadata) only metadata is mapped and not tags:

> Currently, indexing blob index tags isn't supported by this indexer.